# Create element select-option and selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying the code given below :

```js
var tmp1 = "3";
var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' ><option value='0'>Proses</option><option value='1'>Return</option><option value='2' >Selesai</option></select>";

$('select.status_detail_hanca').val(tmp1);
$(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking").append(status_detail_hanca);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tbody_detail_hanca_checking'>

</div>
```

but this code is not working, `tmp1` value from json and this `select-option` in loop `$.each`.I am trying this code also :

```js
var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' ><option value='0'"+ if(tmp1 === '0'){$(this).append("selected")} +">Proses</option><option value='1'"+ if(tmp1 === '0'){$(this).append("selected")} +">Return</option><option value='2'"+ if(tmp1 === '0'){$(this).append("selected")} +">Selesai</option></select>";
```

but, its also not working.
How to solve this problem ?

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. Also Its better to use loop and create a string than hard-coding it

```js
var tmp1 = "3";
var optionList = ["Proses", "Return","Selesai", "TEST", "FOO"]
var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' >";

status_detail_hanca = optionList.reduce(function(p, c, i){
  var _t = "<option value='"+i+"' ";
  if(tmp1 == i){
    _t += "selected='selected'";
  }
  _t += ">" + c + "</option>";
  p += _t;
  return p;
}, status_detail_hanca);
status_detail_hanca += "</select>";
$(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking").append(status_detail_hanca);

$(document).on("change", ".status_detail_hanca", function(){
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tbody_detail_hanca_checking'>

</div>
```

Comment: its work, just missing `=` after `<option value` . thanks very much. whats the name method for it ?

Comment: Oops. Apologies for typo

Comment: Hi Rajesh, how to `select .change()` by your code ? ex. `$("select.status_detail_hanca").on("change", function (){ $('#id_button').removeAttr("disabled")});` . would you show code for me, because i tried like above not working. thanks

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan I have updated my answer. You cannot directly add event listener because that selector is not available when your code runs. For such cases, you should use delegates.

Comment: i tried like this `$("select.status_detail_hanca").delegate("option", "change", function () {
                if ((this.value) == 2){
                    $("select.gudang").removeAttr("disabled").attr("required");
                }
            });` but, not working !.

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan delegate means you will have to bind listener on a higher element. You can refer my snippet in answer.

Comment: HI Rajesh, its very helpful. but, when i tried like `$(document).on("change", ".status_detail_hanca", function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 2) {
                    $(this).find("select.gudang").removeAttr("disabled").attr("required");
                }else{
                   $(this).find("select.gudang").removeAttr("required").attr("disabled");
                }
            });` not work. i use `$(this).find()` because the `select-option` in loop, would you help me again Rajesh ? :) thanks

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan can you create a fiddle. It would be easier for me to understand and give you better solution

Comment: would you see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L3xs3hry/1/) but, its just one `select-option`. i had 3 `select-option` . so i use `this` and `class`

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan Following is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/L3xs3hry/4/). I have added comments to explain. Hope it helps.

Comment: would you see my update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3xs3hry/5/) its three loop, how to change select and effect only one select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122890/discussion-between-rajesh-and-wawan-setiyawan).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prepend()`, `jQuery()` to prepend an `<option>` element to `select.status_detail_hanca` with `value` and `text` set to `tmp1`, and `selected` property set to `true`.

```js
var tmp1 = "3";
var status_detail_hanca = `
  <select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]'>
    <option value='0'>Proses</option>
    <option value='1'>Return</option>
    <option value='2' >Selesai</option>
  </select>`;

$(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking")
.append(status_detail_hanca);

var select = $("select.status_detail_hanca")
.prepend($("<option>", {value:tmp1, selected:true, text: tmp1}));

console.log(select.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='tbody_detail_hanca_checking'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Selection on base of select option text

```
$(".status_detail_hanca option:contains("+ $.trim("Text you want to select") +")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

//Selection on base of select option value

```
$('.status_detail_hanca').val(name);
```

add dot before class name from selecting element by class i.e  $('.ClassName').opertion();